# Await sql query gets skipped by express validator?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, express-validator

I want to check if a category entered by a user really exists before submiting. I validate my fields with express-validator. Normal req.checks like .exists().trim()... work normally but when I try this:

```
.custom(value => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                connection.query("SELECT id FROM cat WHERE cat_name = ?", [value], (err, results) => {
                    if (err)
                        reject(err);
                    if (results[0] == 'undefined')
                        reject(new Error('This topic does not exist or is misspelled.'))
                    resolve();
                })
        });
```

Edit:
It acrually works in the middleware but but not in the function : /

Comment: it may have to do with the`callback` style of `connection.query`, have you tried using `util.promisify` on `connection.query` so that `connection.query` may be `await`ed on?

You should be able to then `await` on `connection.query` and have 'results' that now may be returned with the conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

it may have to do with the`callback` style of `connection.query`, have you tried using `util.promisify` on `connection.query` so that `connection.query` may be `await`ed on?

You should be able to then `await` on `connection.query` and have 'results' that now may be returned with the conditional logic.

```js
const promisifedQuery = util.promisify(connection.query)

await req.check('category', 'This category does not exist yet.')
      .custom( async (value) => {
      const results = await promisifedQuery("SELECT id FROM category WHERE cat_name = ?", [value]);
      
        if(results[0].id > 0){
            return true
        }
        return false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html)

> Custom validators may return Promises to indicate an async validation
> (which will be awaited upon), or throw any value/reject a promise to
> use a custom error message.
>
> Note: if your custom validator returns a promise, it must reject to
> indicate that the field is invalid.

This means just return a Promise for the custom function, you can use Promise syntax (Promise.reject) or `async/await` (throw) to make a invalid result.

Example with Promise.reject:

```js
.custom(value => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query("SELECT id FROM cat WHERE cat_name = ?", [value], (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject('Something went wrong!');
      }

      if (results[0].id <= 0) { // ???
        return reject('This category does not exist yet');
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still doesn't seem to work. It just goes through every time without giving an erro.